# The sorting of items in RecyclerView happens to 9

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-recyclerview

Made sorting for my components in RecyclerView, sorted by numbers. I need to sort from 1 to 100. The problem is that if I enter 10 then it goes after 1 code should go after 9.

I.e

Should be:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

And I have:
1 10 11 12 13 2 4 5 6 7 8 9

This is what my code looks like now, what needs to be fixed to solve my problem?

```
private void sortArray_type() {
        Arrays.sort(mArraysNames);
        recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void sortArrayList_type() {
        Collections.sort(mSkatingRinkScheduleList, (o1, o2) -> o1.get_session_number().compareTo(o2.get_session_number()));
        recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort numbers as below, here a list of numbers is generated and then shuffled with `Collections.shuffle`, and reorderd with `Collections.sort`:

```
List<Integer> list = makeSequence(1, 15);
Collections.shuffle(list);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    Log.d(TAG, "Shuffled ITEM: " + list.get(i));

Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));

Log.d(TAG, "===========================================");
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    Log.d(TAG, "Sorted ITEM: " + list.get(i));


public static List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end) {
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>(end - begin + 1);
    for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++, ret.add(i-1)) ;
    return ret;
}
```

Output:

```
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 11
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 14
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 2
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 8
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 10
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 5
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 13
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 12
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 7
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 6
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 15
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 9
2020-12-28 16:30:42.074 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 1
2020-12-28 16:30:42.075 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 3
2020-12-28 16:30:42.075 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 4
2020-12-28 16:30:42.075 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ===========================================
2020-12-28 16:30:42.075 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 1
2020-12-28 16:30:42.075 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 2
2020-12-28 16:30:42.075 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 3
2020-12-28 16:30:42.075 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 4
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 5
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 6
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 7
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 8
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 9
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 10
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 11
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 12
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 13
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 14
2020-12-28 16:30:42.076 29066-29066/com.zzzz D/LOG_TAG: ITEM: 15
```

As there are some unknown values in your code, you can apply the same in your code

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you have string array with numeric values

you have to use string Comparator

```
Arrays.sort(yourArrayName, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
            }
        });
```